# ARCORE: view(info card) doesn't appear after tap

Tags: java, android-studio, arcore, sceneform

I'm new to arcore and am using sceneform for a project. Specifically, I'm using the solar system example and trying to implement the info cards it has in `Planet.java` to my project. I have the info cards set up(at least i think i do) however, they do not appear on tap. Am I missing something or is there something I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your help.

```java
private void makeinfoCards(ArFragment arFragment, Anchor anchor, Context context) {
        if (infoCard == null) {
            AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
            infoCard = new Node();
            infoCard.setParent(anchorNode);
            infoCard.setEnabled(false);
            infoCard.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(0.0f, 2.90f * INFO_CARD_Y_POS_COEFF, 0.0f));
            //below would hide/bring up the info card on tap
            infoCard.setOnTapListener(  //anchorNode.setOnTapListener doesn't make info card appear either
                    (hitTestResult, motionEvent) -> {
                        infoCard.setEnabled(!infoCard.isEnabled());
                    }
            );
            ViewRenderable.builder()
                    .setView(arFragment.getContext(), R.layout.card_view) //putting context instead makes no difference
                    .build()
                    .thenAccept(
                            (renderable) -> {
                                infoCard.setRenderable(renderable);
                                TextView textView = (TextView) renderable.getView();
                                textView.setText("random");
                            })
                    .exceptionally(
                            (throwable) -> {
                                throw new AssertionError("Could not load plane card view.", throwable);
                            });
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `onTapListener` on the infoCard Node which has been disabled by default. You should use the setOnTapListener on the node which contains the 3D model you will be clicking, try passing the specific node that has the 3D model set as the renderable as an argument to the function instead of the Anchor. If you have the  Node say modelNode which has the 3D model.

In your ARActivity call

```
makeInfoCard(arFragment,modelNode,context);
```

And in the function use

```
private void makeInfoCard(ArFragment arFragment, Node modelNode, Context context){
//
    modelNode.setOnTapListener((hitTestResult, motionEvent) -> {
        infoCard.setEnabled(!infoCard.isEnabled());
    });
//
}
```

Comment: thank you for replying. I have tried using the node that is used for my renderable and still the info card does not show up. I'm honestly in a roadblock as to why it doesn't show. will try another, but tedious, way and hope i can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `Node.OnTapListener` interface and than override onTap method.

When model is going to be projected keep record of model nodes in a list. Here I set card for each node present on a sceneform.

```
@Override
public void onTap(HitTestResult hitTestResult, MotionEvent motionEvent)   {

        modelDataObj = map.get(hitTestResult.getNode()); // get object againt each node
        tvModelName.setText(modelDataObj.getItem_name());
        Picasso.get().load(modelDataObj.get_thumbnail()).placeholder(R.drawable.imageplaceholder).into(imgLoadAddInfoImage);
        tvTitle.setText(modelDataObj.getItem_name());
        tvLoadAddInfoDescText.setText(modelDataObj.getDescription())
}
```

Comment: the sample example solarsystem does have an example using onSingleTap() however, not gonna lie, I don't fully understand it and also don't know how I would implement it for my specific use. thank you for your time and response.

Comment: you will get node from hittest and get node from your list and than display your card . where is you exactly stuck ? please elaborate ?